# Set device volume - UILocalNotification - iphone in silent mode

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

How can i set volume of device(in silent mode) when UILocalNotification is generated when application is in background? I am working on alarm app, so sound has to be played in silent mode too and i am handling app alarm using local notification.

Badly stuck in this issue, not able to play alarm in silent mode.

Please help..

Comment: the silent switch is there for a reason ...

Comment: But alarm should play in silent mode too..

Comment: i disagree with that. the device should vibrate, but no sound should be played. i mean what is a silent mode good for if it does not actually guarantee you that your device will keep silent (except for things like find my iphone alerts)?i find it discussable to allow sound when the user has initiated it directly (started vdeo playback  or sth like that), but that is all. (dunno if apple does this, but if they do they should change it)

Comment: Hi Ahti, it is part of application requirement, which has to be followed. i agree what u say.

Comment: @Ahti default alarm app does play the sound even if you have triggered your iPhone to be silent mode. How they do that?

Answer (score 3):

It is simply not possible. The `UILocalNotification` popup and sound are generated by another system process, and that process observes the device silent mode, so it won't play the notification sound if the device is on silent.

if you want your alarm clock app to play the alarm sound even when device is in silent mode, you will have to play the alarm sound right from your app. To do that, you will need to keep your app running in the background, then you will have to play the alarm sound file while in the background. The later can be done by specifying "audio" that the "Required background modes" property in your info.plist (you will have to add that property to your plist file)

Now, using `AVAudioPlayer`, there is a way to play sound even when device is silent by setting the Audio session category like this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that local notifications are triggered even your app is killed. That leads me to conclusion that it is probably not possible to do that. 
But you can try that like this:

```
 UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
            AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

right before you make your audio session active.

Comment: Thanks Vanya for replying.  But we are not using AVAudioPlayer to play notification, local notifications are occured from operating system. If you think this will work, can u help by giving some sample code.